# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find' in bs4

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was scraping stock tickers from a screener website. I tried the below code.

```
import datetime as dt
import requests
import bs4
import lxml
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
import math
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
from alpha_vantage.techindicators import TechIndicators

url=r'https://www.marketwatch.com/tools/stockresearch/screener/results.asp?submit=Screen&Symbol=true&Symbol=false&ChangePct=true&ChangePct=false&FiftyTwoWeekLow=false&CompanyName=true&CompanyName=false&Volume=true&Volume=false&PERatio=false&Price=true&Price=false&LastTradeTime=false&MarketCap=false&Change=true&Change=false&FiftyTwoWeekHigh=false&MoreInfo=true&MoreInfo=false&SortyBy=Symbol&SortDirection=Descending&ResultsPerPage=OneHundred&TradesShareEnable=false&TradesShareMin=&TradesShareMax=&PriceDirEnable=true&PriceDir=Up&PriceDirPct=100&LastYearEnable=false&LastYearAboveHigh=&TradeVolEnable=false&TradeVolMin=&TradeVolMax=&BlockEnable=false&BlockAmt=&BlockTime=&PERatioEnable=false&PERatioMin=&PERatioMax=&MktCapEnable=false&MktCapMin=&MktCapMax=&MovAvgEnable=false&MovAvgType=Outperform&MovAvgTime=FiftyDay&MktIdxEnable=false&MktIdxType=Outperform&MktIdxPct=&MktIdxExchange=&Exchange=All&IndustryEnable=false&Industry='

res=requests.get(url)
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
tick=soup.find('td', {'class' :'aleft'}).find('a').text
print(tick)
```

But the above error occurred. Please help me!!

Comment: Looking at the page there isn't and `<td>` with `class="aleft"` so your first `.find()` returns `None`.

Comment: <td> tag is not there in the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and it worked perfectly fine. I got the text of the tag that was mentioned to scrape. Have a look in the below screenshot. Please try once again and let me know if you are facing the same issue or not.

[image]

Comment: Yes, yesterday it was showing error, but today it's working fine. Colab is insane!

Comment: Cool. Good that it worked fine now. Otherwise, it would have been headache if you don't get the output but we get with the same code. :)